# Operator does not exist: integer = integer[] in a query with ANY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I frequently used `integer = ANY(integer[])` syntax, but now ANY operator doesn't work. This is the first time I use it to compare a scalar with an integer returned from CTE, but I thought this shouldn't cause problems.

My query:

```
WITH bar AS (
  SELECT array_agg(b) AS bs
  FROM foo
  WHERE c < 3
)
SELECT a FROM foo WHERE b = ANY ( SELECT bs FROM bar);
```

When I run it, it throws following error:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]: WITH bar AS (
>   SELECT array_agg(b) AS bs FROM foo WHERE c < 3 ) SELECT a FROM foo
>   WHERE b = ANY ( SELECT bs FROM bar)

Details in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/71479/2).

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on the error message portion `operator does not exist: integer = integer[]`, it appears that the `bs` column needs to be `unnest`ed, in order to get the right hand side back to an `integer` so the comparison operator can be found:

```
WITH bar AS (
  SELECT array_agg(b) AS bs
  FROM foo
  WHERE c < 3
)
SELECT a
FROM foo
WHERE b = ANY ( SELECT unnest(bs) FROM bar);
```

This results in the output:

```
A
2
3
```

Given the doc for the [ANY function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME):

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized subquery, which must return
>   exactly one column. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared
>   to each row of the subquery result using the given operator, which
>   must yield a Boolean result. The result of ANY is "true" if any true
>   result is obtained. The result is "false" if no true result is found
>   (including the case where the subquery returns no rows).

... the error makes sense, as the left-hand expression is an `integer` -- column `b` -- while the right-hand expression is an array of `integer`s, or `integer[]`, and so the comparison ends up being of the form `integer` = `integer[]`, which doesn't have an operator, and therefore results in the error.

`unnest`ing the `integer[]` value makes the left- and right-hand expressions `integer`s, and so the comparison can continue.

Modified [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/71479/14/0).

**Note:** that the same behavior is seen when using `IN` instead of `= ANY`.

Comment: Additional explanation based on your answer: Because `1 = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3])` is legal, it is reasonable to also expect `1 = ANY(SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3])` to be legal, but it isn't because that'd create an ambiguity about whether you wanted `1 = ARRAY[1,2,3]` or `1 = 1 OR 1 = 2 OR 1 = 3` and the parser isn't smart enough to figure out that only one can be legal. You can tell it that you really want the array-ANY form with `1 = ANY( (SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3])::int[] )` (which I would do instead of `unnest`ing).

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks for the additional details.

Comment: @CraigRinger: thank you! Ken's answer helped me how to do it right, but your comment made me understand why my query was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

without unnest

```
WITH bar AS (
  SELECT array_agg(b) AS bs
  FROM foo
  WHERE c < 3
)
SELECT a FROM foo WHERE ( SELECT b = ANY (bs) FROM bar);
```

Comment: But it seems slower .

Answer (score 1):

FYI, For me,

`SELECT ... WHERE "id" IN (SELECT unnest(ids) FROM tablewithids)`

was incomparably faster than

`SELECT ... WHERE "id" = ANY((SELECT ids FROM tablewithids)::INT[])`

Didn't do any research into why that was though.

Answer (score 0):

column needs to be unnest

WITH bar AS (
  SELECT array_agg(b) AS bs
  FROM foo
  WHERE c < 3
)
SELECT a
FROM foo
WHERE b = ANY ( SELECT unnest(bs) FROM bar);

Comment: How is this different than the existing answer?