# How to get ids of grouped by rows in postgresql and use result?

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a table containing transactions with an amount. I want to create a batch of transactions so that the sum of amount of each 'group by' is negative. 
My problematic is to get all ids of the rows concerned by a 'group by' where each group is validate by a sum condition.

I find many solutions which don't work for me.
The best solution I found is to request the db a first time with the 'group by' and the sum, then return ids to finally request the db another time with all of them.

Here an example of what I would like (it doesn't work!) :

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_table transaction 
AND transaction.id IN (
    select string_agg(grouped::character varying, ',' ) from (
        SELECT array_agg(transaction2.id) as grouped FROM transaction_table transaction2 
        WHERE transaction2.c_scte='c'
        AND (same conditions)
        GROUP BY
            transaction2.motto ,
            transaction2.accountBnf ,
            transaction2.payment ,
            transaction2.accountClt 
        HAVING sum(transaction2.amount)<0
    )
);
```

the result of the array_agg is like:

```
{39758,39759}
{39757,39756,39755,39743,39727,39713}
```

and the string_agg is :

```
{39758,39759},{39757,39756,39755,39743,39727,39713}
```

Now I just need to use them but I don't know how to...

unfortunatly, it doesn't work because of type casting :

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
  Indice : No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for

```
SELECT id, motto, accountbnf, payment, accountclnt, amount
FROM (SELECT id, motto, accountbnf, payment, accountclnt, amount,
             sum(amount)
                OVER (PARTITION BY motto, accountbnf, payment, accountclnt)
                AS group_total
      FROM transaction_table) AS q
WHERE group_total < 0;
```

The inner `SELECT` adds an additional column using a window function that calculates the sum for each group, and the outer query removes all results where that sum is not negative.

Comment: This doesn't works for me, the compiler tells their is an error near ')'. I found a solution that I just posted

Comment: Indeed, there is a comma missing @Laurenz ```[...] accountclnt, amount !,! sum(amount) [...]```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found this option using the 'unnest' method. It works perfectly.

- Array_agg bring together all ids in different array
- unnest flattened all of them

This comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600598/operator-does-not-exist-integer-integer-in-a-query-with-any)

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_table transaction 
WHERE transaction.id = ANY(
    SELECT unnest(array_agg(transaction2.id)) as grouped FROM transaction_table transaction2 
    WHERE transaction2.c_scte='c'
    AND (same conditions)
    GROUP BY
        transaction2.motto ,
        transaction2.accountBnf ,
        transaction2.payment ,
        transaction2.accountClt 
    HAVING sum(transaction2.amount)<0
);
```

The problem with this solution is that hibernate doesn't take into account the array_agg method.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just tried the request without the unnest and it throw this error :"ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
  Indice : No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts." I tried to cast it but I get the same result. unnest method seems to be important in my case. Perhaps due to my postgreSQL database...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Definitly not, I've not removed the `any`!! I just removed the `unnset()`. Please try on your side, `= any(select array_agg(....) ...)` just doesn't work without the `unnest()` when there're 2 or more rows returned and that's pretty logic.